# How can I duplicate animations in bevy?

Tags: rust, game-engine, game-development, bevy

How can I create and use duplicate entities with animations in bevy? The animation for the following seems to work fine if I only load a single fish. If I load multiple, the animations don't play.

```
struct Animations(Vec<Handle<AnimationClip>>);

fn setup_fish(
    mut commands: Commands,
    asset_server: Res<AssetServer>,
    mut rng: ResMut<Rng>,
) {
    commands.insert_resource(Animations(vec![
        asset_server.load("models/Fish_anim.gltf#Animation0"),
    ]);

    let scene: Handle<Scene> = asset_server.load("models/Fish_anim.gltf#Scene0");
    for _ in 0..10 {
        commands
            .spawn_bundle(TransformBundle {
                local: Transform::from_xyz(
                    rng.gen_range(10.0..20.0),
                    rng.gen_range(1.0..10.0),
                    rng.gen_range(10.0..20.0)),
                global: GlobalTransform::identity(),
            })
            .with_children(|parent| {
                parent.spawn_scene(scene.clone());
            })
            .insert(Fish);
    }
}

fn setup_scene_once_loaded(
    animations: Res<Animations>,
    mut players: Query<&mut AnimationPlayer, Added<AnimationPlayer>>,
) {
    for mut player in players.iter_mut() {
        player.play(animations.0[0].clone_weak()).repeat();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `clone_weak` to `clone` seems to have fixed it.